# Get laptop monitor model

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I need to replace the monitor on a Clevo P775DM3 17.3'laptop, which has Windows 10 installed. Without taking the laptop apart, is there a way I can get the part number, serial number, make and/or model from the OS?

Thanks
Jorge

Comment: There are monitors here for that laptop. The specific model number is not show but all the replacement information is shown: https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/model/Clevo/P775DM3-G/

Comment: actually I wanted to confirm the serial number to be sure, but that ended up being what I did. Thanks! :)

Comment: If I post my comment as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: Quoting the great Teal'c of Chulak: "Indeed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are monitors here for that laptop. The specific model number is not show but all the replacement information is shown:

laptopscreen.com/English/model/Clevo/P775DM3-G